# How to restore exported RDS snapshot from S3 to RDS cluster

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I have an AWS RDS Aurora PostgreSQL cluster (compatible with PostgreSQL 13.4).

I **successfully** followed [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_ExportSnapshot.html) tutorial to back up my PostgreSQL RDS aurora cluster snapshot to S3, and it seems that all the data is backed up to s3.

Now I'm trying to restore the exported snapshot from S3 to PostgreSQL RDS cluster, and I couldn't find explanation how to do it.

Any idea how to do it? maybe I need to first restore the exported data from S3 to snapshot, and then connect it to to RDS, or any other way?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[The RDS Snapshot to S3 export feature](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_ExportSnapshot.html) is not intended for additional backups of your data. It is intended to convert your data to Parquet for use in analytics tools like Redshift or Athena. Some data type conversion happens during this export process.

There is currently no method available to import these Parquet files back into RDS. You would have to write some code yourself to read the Parquet files and insert the data back into a running RDS instance if you needed that.

If you are just wanting a secondary backup of your RDS instance in addition to the RDS snapshots, you could either look into cross-region or cross-account [copies of your RDS snapshots](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_CopySnapshot.html), or look into using the [AWS Backup](https://aws.amazon.com/backup/) service.

Comment: So what is the solution to back up and restore? is there a build in solution?

Comment: @Yagel did you not read the last paragraph in my answer?

Comment: yeah sorry, missed that (: thx!

Comment: If it is not intended for creating backups, why is it that the S3 export is in the "Backing up and restoring a DB instance" section of the documentation and why is there a big "Restore from s3" button on the RDS instances list page?

Comment: @Luke that's a good question for an AWS employee. The fact of the matter is that it exports in a format that cannot be re-imported back into RDS.

Comment: Cheers Mark. The pertinent point in the documentation that I hadn't spotted is `You can't restore exported snapshot data from S3 to a new DB instance.`. Well I better cancel the 5 backups that are currently creating in my account then 

Comment: Christ almighty I've just realised it costs to export to S3 for the process itself, not just storage. I exported about 10 snapshots for a database 20gb in size and it cost over $23 USD :|