# How to copy an rds snapshot from a sub region (ap-east-1) to a main one (us-east-1)?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, aws-regions

When running the aws cli command:

```
aws rds copy-db-cluster-snapshot \
    --source-db-cluster-snapshot-identifier arn:aws:rds:ap-east-1:<account-id>:cluster-snapshot:rds:<cluster-identifier>-2022-09-19-11-18 \
    --target-db-cluster-snapshot-identifier hk-2022-09-19 \
    --source-region ap-east-1 \
    --region eu-west-1
```

The following is thrown:

> An error occurred (InvalidParameterValue) when calling the CopyDBClusterSnapshot operation: Cross region operations are not supported between ap-northeast-2 and ap-east-1 regions

---

Also tried:

```
aws rds create-db-instance-read-replica \
    --db-instance-identifier "my-readonly-replica" \
    --source-db-instance-identifier "arn:aws:rds:ap-east-1:<account-id>:db:<instance-id>" \
    --source-region ap-east-1 \
    --region us-west-1
```

To no avail. with following error:

> An error occurred (InvalidDBInstanceState) when calling the CreateDBInstanceReadReplica operation: Cross-Region Read Replicas are not supported for the provided source DB Instance engine version. Please upgrade to a supported engine version and try again.

---

The db is of an Aurora PostgreSQL:14.3 cluster. What are my options? How can I transfer a snapshot from an `ap-east-1` region to anywhere else (in the management console ui when copy is selected in the actions of the snapshot, only region can be copied is the same region)?

Any way more performant than

1. create & connect to an ec2 instance
2. connect to the db
3. use pgsql commands to get db dump
4. compress the dump file
5. upload to s3
6. create an empty db in the target region
7. create & connect to an ec2 instance in the target region
8. download the s3 uploaded db dump
9. decompress the file
10. run the dump against the db server in the target region
11. take snapshot of the db cluster in the target region

?

Comment: what about export to s3?

Comment: @Riz There is no method available to [import these snapshot back into RDS from S3 bucket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72547543/how-to-restore-exported-rds-snapshot-from-s3-to-rds-cluster)

Comment: @duyguevrim, you are right for this case. You could try to make a cross region read replica and then make it master later.

Comment: Checked and aws backup isn't available as well in ap-east-1. By the way, according to https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/Concepts.RDSFeaturesRegionsDBEngines.grids.html#Concepts.RDS_Fea_Regions_DB-eng.Feature.CrossRegionReadReplicas, Cross-Region read replicas are available for all Regions.

Comment: You don't need the `source region`. It's for creating an encrypted read replica between the AWS GovCloud (US-East) and AWS GovCloud (US-West) Regions. Can you remove it and try again? I know the error says somethig else but aws cli sometimes throws error which are totally different than the actual errors.

Comment: The last option I can think of is the use of `AWS Database Migration Service`.